# Continous conversation based on last message in Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: botframework

I want continuous conversation chat in Microsoft Bot framework.

if(user says hello)
{
     reply = `what u want to listen hi or hello`
-----if(user says hi)
-----{
--------reply= `hi`
-----}
----if(user says hello)
-- {
-------reply= `hello`
---}
}

means bot should also ask question and answer it accordingly..

Comment: Please clarify what your asking and format the post accordingly. Is hard to understand what you are currently asking

Comment: I have tried to format.. i want bot will ask question and based on last question it will reply..

Comment: What language are u using? C# or Node?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is `C#` and that you are using an `IDialog<T>` based dialog, you could do the following:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    if (message.Text.Equals("hello", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        PromptDialog.Text(context, this.ResumeAfterPrompt, "What u want to listen hi or hello");
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}

private async Task ResumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    try
    {
        var userMessage = await result;

        switch (userMessage.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "hi":
                await context.PostAsync("hi");
                break;
            case "hello":
                await context.PostAsync("hello");
                break;
            default:
                // do something;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
    {
        // do something with the exception
    }

    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```